# Reverse mask with multiple overlapping rectangles

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, cgpath

I have a rectangle that I'm trying to do a reverse mask on, removing a variable number of *other* rectangles from the original shape.

If I were just trying to remove *one* rectangle, this would be easy, using an evenOdd fill. However, once I have multiple rectangles, the intersections of those rectangles become filled again. See the below example:

[image]

In the above example, I ideally, I wouldn't see the small red squares, which are the intersections of the 3 shapes overlayed onto the red background. In other words, the ideal is the *inverse* of this:

[image]

Is there any way I can eliminate the extra crossings in my `Path` so that the entire area "covered" by my `Shape` will get reverse-masked out?

Reproducible code to get to the first image:

```
struct MyShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        
        p.addRect(rect)
        
        p.addRect(.init(origin: .init(x: 60, y: 60),
                        size: .init(width: 100, height: 100)))

        p.addRect(.init(origin: .init(x: 120, y: 120),
                        size: .init(width: 100, height: 100)))
        
        p.addRect(.init(origin: .zero,
                        size: .init(width: 100, height: 100)))
        
        return p
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .mask(
                    MyShape()
                        .fill(style: .init(eoFill: true))
                )
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
    }
}
```

**Note:** I'm on `macOS`, but have a deployment target of 11.3, so a solution using `CGPath`'s `intersection` won't work.

Also worth noting that in my basic example, I could hard code the path by hand, but assume that the overlayed rectangles are coming in dynamically, so hardcoding a path also isn't workable.

Comment: Since I want the background to be clear, I suppose an extreme solution would be to paint the rectangles on in a color I know won't appear elsewhere, render the `View` to a bitmap, and then turn all of the alpha channels of that color to `clear`, but that seems... extreme. Hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use your shape directly as a mask, you can create a "reverse mask" using `.blendMode(.destinationOut)` to "cut out" a shape from a `Rectangle`, then the result is used as the mask:

```
struct MyShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        p.addRect(CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 100, height: 100))
        p.addRect(CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 100, height: 100))
        p.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        return p
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
            ZStack {
                Color.red.mask {
                    // Mask is Rectangle with MyShape removed
                    Rectangle()
                        .overlay() {
                            MyShape()
                                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                        }
                }
                .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

A full (and excellent) explanation as to how this all works can be found here:

https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/reverse-masks-how-to/

Comment: Thanks for the insight! In my question, I'm using a `clear` background color on macOS. I'm seeing some somewhat inconsistent behavior where using `destinationOut` *sometimes* leads to a `black` background rather than `clear`. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I replaced the `Color.yellow` with `Color.clear` and it still works OK for me running on a Mac (Xcode 14.2, macOS 13.1)

Comment: Weird -- I see it sporadically, but I can't nail down a pattern. Will update if I find one!